# Html video outside Webroot

Tags: html, apache

How do I access a video file outside webroot using HTML5 Video tag? The src attribute is able to access only the video files under webroot. Any possible solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can give the absolute URL in the src attribute.

```
<video controls autoplay>
<source  id="mp4" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
</video>
```

make sure to set the MIME type properly cause some browsers don't play remote  videos if the MIME is not properly set.

Comment: Thanks. But I meant, outside webroot, but inside the server (a different path, say D drive). Not outside the server

Comment: @user3065499: hi ,check this link , it might solve your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357994/access-a-file-which-is-located-before-outside-the-server-root-directory