# Playing audio using javascript outside of my app

Tags: javascript, audio

I wanna know if its possibly play an audio located another folder outside project.

something like this:

My index.html is at location: **/var/www/html/myProject**

And the audio location is:

```
<source src="/var/opt/mp3/song.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access a file which is located before / outside the server root directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357994/access-a-file-which-is-located-before-outside-the-server-root-directory)

Comment: nope, because I want play the audio with Javascript, In your example link is with PHP

Comment: I think you could do it with `PHP` but not a direct link :/

Comment: If you could do it in JavaScript or HTML you have a problem.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes, thinking better, It's impossibly acces another file via HTTP, otherwise it would be an serious security problem , I think.. If someone can confirm this, we can close this post.

Comment: I think the answer is, no this is not possible without a server-side solution.